# jqGrid rowformatter based on separate cells value

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I want to change the colour of a single cell based on the text contained in it. The cell will be a status, so either new, sent or assigned. The issue is that this text value is translatable so a formatter such as the code below will not work correctly.

```js
function StatusColourFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject){
    if(cellValue === 'NULL' || cellValue === 'undefined' || cellValue === 'null' || cellValue === null || cellValue === ' ' || cellValue == '&nbsp'){
        cellValue = '';
        return cellValue;
    }
    if(cellValue == "New"){
        rowsNew[rowsNew.length] = options.rowId;
        return cellValue;
        }

     if(cellValue == "Sent"){
        rowsSent[rowsSent.length] = options.rowId;
        return cellValue
        }
     if(cellValue =="Assigned"){
        rowsAssigned[rowsAssigned.length] = options.rowId;
        return cellValue
     }
}
```

So what i want to do is have a hidden column were the value is always in english but then i want to change the colour of the cell that holds the translated value. Is this possible, and how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the text of the cell or the background color can be changed by setting `class` or `style` attribute on the cell (on `<td>`). jqGrid have `cellattr` callback which helps here. It's important to understand that the goal of the custom formatter is building of the *cell content* and not the *cell attributes*. To change the cell attributes one should use `cellattr`.

Thus I recommend you to assign different `class` attribute based on the content of the cell

```js
cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue) { //, rawObject, cm, item) {
    switch (cellValue) {
        case "New":
            return "class='new_color'";
            break;
        case "Sent":
            return "class='sent_color'";
            break;
        case "Assigned":
            return "class='assigned_color'";
            break;
    }
}
```

To set the value based on the content of another item (not the current `cellValue`) one should add `rawObject, cm, item` parameters to `cellValue` and to use `item` or `rawObject` object. In the most cases the choose of the `item` parameter with the column name as the property would be the best choice for free jqGrid.

Additionally one should define the CSS rules, which uses the classes and set the `color` or `background-color` for example as the following

```css
.new_color {
    background-color: green;
}
.sent_color {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.assigned_color {
    background-color: red;
}
.new_color, .sent_color, .assigned_color {
    background-image: none;
}
```